# Can we control what contact name links to on reports?

Tags: reports

We have a lot of "Contact Reports" set up and in some of them the contact name links to the contact record but in others it links to another report.

I can't see what it is that influences this. Is it configurable?

Comment: Are the ones that are linking to others Summary reports aren't they, which they take  you through to the Detail report?

Comment: Yes, that seems right. We have some reports on the dashboard that are lists of clients, team members etc and would like them to link to the contact but some do and some don't. I guess the answer is to rewrite the ones that don't as detail rather than summary reports. I'll try that - thanks!

Comment: I rewrote as an Answer to keep SE happy. you did well to interpret my gibberish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the ones that are linking to others are Summary reports which then take you through to the Detail report. You could try to rewrite the ones that don't click through, and which you want to do so, as Detail rather than Summary reports

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try Jon G's extension first though as it might be easier than rewriting all the reports.

Answer (score 4):

This is not configurable out of the box - but I really don't like when clicking on a name in a report doesn't bring you to the contact record.  For that reason, I've written an extension called "No Drill Down", which modifies any report that would normally bring you to a Contact Detail or Contribution Detail, and instead brings you to the contact record.  You can [find it here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-drill-down).

Comment: Nice one Jon G.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm missing something... I installed the module, it's enabled, but existing reports still link to the summary report. Does the module only work with reports created after it is installed?

Comment: Actually I just created a new report and it still isn't working for me ...

Comment: @naomi What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.7.3

Comment: @naomi - Hmm, I tested on that version.  Which report template are you using?  Does the extension work when you use the Contact Summary report?

Comment: Do you mean Constituent Summary? I don't see a template for Contact Summary. I created a Constituent Summary report and the names link to Constituent Details :(

Comment: @naomi Yes, sorry - internally it's called the Contact Summary report, the web UI label is Constituent Summary.  That said, I just tested it on two different sites, and it's working for me in both - 4.7.1 and 4.7.4.  I'm not sure why it's not working for you, sorry!

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help - I'll do some debugging